# How to set an image in the background of custom view

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

How can one set image from uri to the background of custom view without causing the stackoverflow error. As I couldn't find any appropriate answers, I hope to find it here.

Comment: check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18870654/5453659
you can download the image from uri to a bitmap and use method in the link to set as background.

Comment: When I did that I got an error say stackoverflow 8mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get that image via Picasso / Glide libraries as a Bitmap
2. Convert Bitmap to drawable

   `Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);`
3. Set drawable to your custom view

   `yourCustomView.setBackground(drawable);`

Comment: Kindly check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676704/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-stack-size-8mb-while-setting-background-image-capt/55676746?noredirect=1#comment98041163_55676746